# Изменить битность операционной системы, которую я пишу сам?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, ос, x86-64

Я пишу ОС. Из-за того, что у меня мало опыта, я умею только заниматься этим для 32-бит (моя ОС получается 32-битная), но я хочу сделать ее 64-битной.

Что мне делать?

Вот код моего кернела конкретно для ассемблера:

```
.set MAGIC, 0x1badb002
.set FLAGS, (1<<0 | 1<<1)
.set CHECKSUM, -(MAGIC + FLAGS)

.section .multiboot
  .long MAGIC
  .long FLAGS
  .long CHECKSUM

.section .text
.extern kernelMain
.global loader

loader:
    mov $kernel_stack, %esp
    push %eax
    push %ebx
    call kernelMain

_stop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp _stop

.section .bss
.space 2*1024*1024; # 2 megabytes of space
kernel_stack:
```

Он еще, конечно, не закончен, но близко.
И еще немного информации:
Я компилирую свой код на GNU Assembler при помощи `as` в Ubuntu; C++ код при помощи `g++`.

Если найдете дупликаты, пожалуйста, скиньте ссылку.

Comment: Cолидно........

Comment: Можно погуглить, но я в этом вообще ничего не понимаю так что вот только [ссылка](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/multiboot.html)

Comment: Ну если человек может наваять такой код, то как ему вообще что-то может быть трудно...

Comment: А как вы это вообще запускаете?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109346/discussion-between-leopardl-gd-and-victor-vosmottor-thanks-monica).

Comment: Я не читал всю предыдущую дискуссию, но судя по коду выше и подразумевая, что ты не используешь какой-то специфический загрузчик, это 16-битная «ОС», а не 32-х битная... так что прежде, чем соваться в amd64 я бы посоветовал сначала перейти в защищённый режим: этого хватит на неделю-другую веселья с разбором, что за линия A20(и что такое безумие обратной совместимости), как инициализировать GDT итп... а потом уж переход в «длинный режим» будет абсолютной банальностью...

Comment: Использую GRUB и в основном qemu-system-i386 для запуска. Вообще не шарю, что за защищенный режим, можешь тоже зайти в дискуссию?

Comment: Если, вы вообще не шарите, что за защищенный режим (protected mode), то переходить к 64-битному режиму (64-bit mode) точно рано, т. к. вам придется настроить прерывания (IDT), виртуальную память посредством paging,  а также заполнить GDT. Задача не самая тривиальная.

Comment: @LeopardLGD, в этом деле вам никто не помощник, придется курить кучу манов и в первую очередь Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual.

Comment: На самом деле ты мне сейчас помог, я почитаю @eanmos Можешь перенести это в ответ, но добавь что-нибудь и я приму

Comment: @LeopardLGD, не спеши, на вопрос-то я не ответил. Может, кто-то еще напишет ответ.

Comment: У Горлова спросите. Он уже написал  книгу Как написа написать РусОС на Ассемблере

Comment: Вы привели в пример 16-битный загрузчик ядра. Данного кода достаточно что бы запустить как 32-битную ОС так и 64-битную. Остальное уже описали - вам прийдется переходить в защищенный режим (100%) и так далее.

Comment: Возможно вопрос следует задать по другому, скажем, например, у меня есть "кастомное ядро линукса". Я его так-то собираю. Можно ли это ядро собрать под 64-бита. Тогда вам может ответы дадут лучше. Я с ноля пытался что-то 32-битное писать, давно бросил. Очень мало людей могут с ноля такое сделать, и думаю если смогут - то и такой вопрос задавать не будут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Приведенный код совсем не похож на код операционной системы. У вас просто происходит вызов функции kernelMain и последующий бесконечный цикл ожидания аппаратных прерываний. Преобразовывать в 64-битный режим тут нечего, этот код будет выглядеть идентично в любом режиме.

Переход в 64-битный режим в процессорах Intel x86 осуществляется установкой флага LME (бит 8) в регистре Extended Feature Enable Register (EFER). См. [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html), Volume 3: System Programming Guide, раздел 2.2.1

[image: efer]

Инструкция, которая заполняет этот регистр - [wrmsr](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrmsr).

После этого нужно заполнить GDT так, чтобы в ней был сегмент кода с флагом 64-битного режима (21 бит в дескрипторе), и, соответственно, выполнить код в этом сегменте. Подробнее можно почитать здесь: https://wiki.osdev.org/User:Stephanvanschaik/Setting_Up_Long_Mode