# Создание ISO загрузочной флешки для запуска через BIOS

Tags: linux, bios, iso-образ

Мне необходимо создать и записать на флешку образ, который при запуске через BIOS будет выводить на экран текст и/или изображение. Я прошерстила интернет, но нашла только инструкции по созданию загрузочной флешки Windows или Linux.

Насколько я понимаю, без драйверов ничего не вывести на экран. Следовательно мне нужно собрать свой дистрибутив, который просто будет выводить на экран заранее записанный текст или показывать заранее сохранённое изображение. (Больше мне ничего не нужно. Просто при загрузке вывод чего-либо на экран)

Собственно вопросы, которые я хотела задать:

- Я мыслю в правильном направлении?
  Если да, то следующий вопрос:
- Как можно что-то подобное собрать на ядре linux?

Comment: для того, чтобы что-то вывести на экран, вам не нужна программа linux. и других вариантов программ, выполняющих функции ядра операционной системы, не нужно. следовательно, не требуется вам и (странных) сущностей, которые вы назвали «драйверами».

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin тогда что нужно сделать для запуска флешки через BIOS и последущего вывода текста или картинки на экран, без использования операционных систем, установленных на ПК?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1140968/178576 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1144089/178576 и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin понятно. спасибо

Comment: А какая цель преследуется? Чисто академически минимальным кодом вывести хеллоуворлд или сделать из старого компа а-ля часы с кукушкой?

Comment: @donRumata академический интерес. Вывести на экран текст.

Comment: Если я правильно нашла, то мне надо написать asm программу, сделать бинарник, а потом его можно сделать iso и записать на флешку. Надеюсь правильно поняла

Comment: Лучше поискать готовые инструкции, они должны быть. Теоретически всё очень просто: создаёте ASM с org0, режим 16 бит, делаете ds=cs, а дальше через `int 10h` выводите на экран. В хвост - надо спецметку дописать, по адресу 1F8h должна быть особая метка 55-что-то. Программа должна быть не более 508 байт. Точнее весь блок должен быть 512 байт и оканчиваться загрузочной сигнатурой. Сигнатуру можно подглянуть в любом загрузчике.

Comment: Если нет загрузчика - достать его можно или старой diskedit загрузившить с DOS, или акрониксом, или поискать на просторах сети.